# Microsoft Word-safe fonts

Tags: fonts, microsoft-word

If I type up my resume in, let's say, a Windows-specific font like Segoe UI and I send it to someone who opens in on a Mac, what font are they going to see?

Maybe Segoe isn't a good example, but if I stick any crazy font on there that someone else definitely doesn't have installed, how does their MS Word handle it?

Comment: If someone is willing to open _Word_ files from complete strangers, they're certainly braver than I am.

Comment: I'm not sure what Word does for substitute fonts. Adobe has a very clever substitute font that it uses for PDFs, maybe you should convert to PDF.

Comment: This is a site for programmers and your question is clearly off-topic. Please read the FAQ before posting questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct Word to embed the font. Whether the consuming app on the Mac knows how to deal with this is another question.

To embed fonts, File > Options > Save > Embed fonts in the file

Answer (score -2):

The default fault font for Ms Word is Times New Roman ... so if you sent any document to any PC type word will be able to open it even if you used a different font

Comment: (On Windows, unsure about OS X) The default body font has been Calibri since Office 2007; headings are Cambria, equations are Cambria Math, etc.